# gcc's option dose not work until newer version

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I recently struggle with gcc's optimization, hope to help with performance improvement.

I found the option `-freorder-blocks-and-partition`.

(This option exist on very old versions of gcc, such as gcc 5.6.)

It can be used to partition cold/hot cold to separate function, together with `-ffunction-sections` and linker script, cold/hot code can be put into separate ELF sections (.text section and .text.cold section).

But this option only works on recent gcc version.

I test it on gcc 10.1, and use the following compiler exploration tool, make sure it works start from version 8.1:

in gcc8.1: https://godbolt.org/z/hGcnMM, the assembly code contains a function like this:

```
fa(int, int) [clone .cold.0]:
```

In gcc7.1: https://godbolt.org/z/rhqjE1, the assembly code does not contain such function.

Why does it not work on older gcc?

And is there any way to control the older version gcc to apply this optimization?